# Which Framework can be used to draw a complex, interactive UI hierarchy on Android? (Like CoreAnimation on iOS)

Tags: android, view, imageview, layer

I'm porting a vector graphics editor from iOS to Android. The app must draw a complex hierarchy of graphical objects in an efficient manner, so that the graphics can be edited with gestures in real time. The edited work commonly consists of images, text and graphical primitives (lines, circles etc.). UI elements like selection highlights are rendered on a separate layer on the top.

On the iOS app, if one component of the graphic changes (for example a small text element changes its content), only that text element is re-rendered.

On iOS, we use `CALayer` objects from the `CoreAnimation` framework. This works very well. What framework can be used on Android for this use case? Is there an established "native" way to do that, or are usually third party frameworks used?

Comment: Complex graphics on Android are usually implemented using `SurfaceView`. Not sure if it fits your needs, but another option may be to look in to Gaming frameworks like libgdx or unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not have similar thing out of the box. We do have [core.animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/animation/package-summary) but it is limited to simple behavioral animations. To create what you want you need to use [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) or [`GLSurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView) and help of clean [`OpenGL`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl). You may also try to use ordinary [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) of `View` - you will have limited possibilities though.

Also there are wrapper around `OpenGl` and `SurfaceView` like [`libgdx`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) it is used mostly for games though - so it has much wider possibilities than you need, but it is less complicated than `OpenGl`.

Hope it helps.